Excel Sum from cell based on criteria from this same cell
I have data setup in below format:



Cell 1
Cell 2
Cell 3
Cell 4
Cell 5
SF Total
DD  Total




1,5 SF
1 SF
2 DD
1 DD
1 SF
3,5
3



without splitting data set i need get the sum of the values for columns which meet criteria,
For example sum all values for columns where there is "SF".
I have working solution build on array where i can sum up all values however adding criteria for specific text SF or DD etc is not working at all and i can't get my head around.
Is anyone having some smart idea?
Formula which is showing sum for values at the beginning of the cell value depending on the data from this same cell.

Try using the following formula:


=SUM((TEXTAFTER($A2:$E2," ")=LEFT(F$1,2))*TEXTBEFORE($A2:$E2," "))


Or, Spill it using BYCOL()
=BYCOL(LEFT(F1:G1,2),LAMBDA(α, SUM((TEXTAFTER(A2:E2," ")=α)*TEXTBEFORE(A2:E2," "))))



Using MMULT() --> Simple I think: =TOROW(MMULT((RIGHT(A2:E2,2)=TOCOL(LEFT(F1:G1,2)))*TEXTBEFORE(A2:E2," "),SEQUENCE(5)^0))

Try:
=SUM((1*TEXTBEFORE($A$2:$E$2," "))*(TEXTAFTER($A$2:$E$2," ")=F1))

Result:

Wrap with IFERROR if necessary:
=SUM((1*IFERROR(TEXTBEFORE($A$2:$E$2," "),0))*(IFERROR(TEXTAFTER($A$2:$E$2," "),0)=F1))


you can eliminate the 1*:  =SUM(TEXTBEFORE($A$2:$E$2," ")*(TEXTAFTER($A$2:$E$2," ")=F1))  The fact that you multiply the result by the Boolean is sufficient.  Just an FYI, not a criticism.

Indeed! I think it was left from other formula variations while building it!

Verbose, for fun:
=LAMBDA(data, delim,
    LET(
        vals, TOCOL(NUMBERVALUE(TEXTBEFORE(data, delim))),
        cats, TOCOL(TRIM(TEXTAFTER(data, delim))),
        uniq, UNIQUE(cats),
        sums, REDUCE(
            "",
            uniq,
            LAMBDA(acc, c, VSTACK(acc, SUM(FILTER(vals, cats = c))))
        ),
        result, TRANSPOSE(HSTACK(uniq & " Total", DROP(sums, 1))),
        result
    )
)(B4:F4, " ")



With functions which work in older Excel also.
=SUM(VALUE(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("SF";A1:E1)>0;0);LEFT(A1:E1;SEARCH(" ";A1:E1));0)))
=SUM(VALUE(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("DD";A1:E1)>0;0);LEFT(A1:E1;SEARCH(" ";A1:E1));0)))
